# Convertir código XAML(WPF) a código C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Buen día, estoy intentando crear la siguiente estructura XAML desde código C#. ¿Podrían ayudarme por favor?

```
  <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True">

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=onScreenKeyboard}" />

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

La idea es crear 3 columnas como esta pero desde code behind.

Comment: ¿Has probado ver la documentación oficial de WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, tu etiquetado XAML se puede simplificar, si solo quieres bindear un texto basta con declarar la columna de la forma común, en vez de:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=onScreenKeyboard}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Hacerlo así:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=onScreenKeyboard}" Header="Item" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Y respecto a la pregunta, deberías poder añadir esa misma columna desde el code-behind de este modo:

```
void Code()
{
    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
    column.Header = "Item";
    column.Width = 150;
    column.IsReadOnly = true;
    column.Binding = new Binding("Text.onScreenKeyboard"); //ver nota al final
    myDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);

}
```

Suerte!.
NOTA: En el binding lo puse como propiedad pues no especificas si el "onScreenKeyboard" es una referencia al teclado en pantalla nativo del S.O. o una propiedad de un control que la llamaste así.. si es el teclado no necesitas bindearlo.